# What's the impact of super high VSWR? Need help from experts

Tags: antenna, efficiency, bandwidth

Is it realistic to make an antenna system with VSWR as high as 20 to transmit 50MHz signal? I am thinking of increasing bandwidth of a small antenna by sacrificing its mismatch efficiency. Assuming the low transmission power is acceptable, is the signal distortion going to be a problem?

Updated:
I am thinking about the possibility of designing a small antenna (a few centimeters long) for transmitting 50MHz signal. Bode limit gives an theoretical upper bound for efficiency bandwidth product. I am wondering whether it is possible to sacrifice efficiency for 1MHz bandwidth with such a small antenna.

Comment: One thing you need to be concerned about is whether your transmitter's output stage can handle that reflected power without damage.

Comment: What kind of bandwidth do you need? More detail about your proposed system design would interest me.

Comment: @Bryan, I updated my question to include it.

Comment: https://www.antenna-theory.com/m/definitions/vswr.php

Comment: VSWR and fractional bandwidth are frequency-independent parameters; what relevance is the 50MHz? Are there other useful, underlying details omitted that would relate to this? What about signal level; you mention distortion as a concern, but antennas and matching networks are generally linear, where would distortion come into this? Or do you mean more informally i.e. the wave shape or spectrum may become "distorted" (warped in some way or another)?

Comment: What type of antenna is it? I ask because if the VSWR rises to 20 at the extremes of the sidebands then it doesn't sound like a monopole or dipole.

Comment: .02 (2%) is a pretty narrow bandwidth.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I am thinking about the possibility of designing a small antenna (a few centimeters long) for transmitting 50MHz signal. Bode limit gives an theoretical upper bound for efficiency bandwidth product. I am wondering whether it is possible to sacrifice efficiency for 1MHz bandwidth.